# Limit an Excel cell to one of two possible values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, data-validation

I would like to create a cell format for one cell to only allow the value "yes" or "no" for this cell.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Microsoft describes this here: [Apply data validation to cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249)

1. Click the cell you want to restrict value for
2. Go to **Data** -> **Validation**.  The Data Validation dialog box opens
3. In the *Allow* dropdown select **List**
4. In the *Source* text box enter `Yes,No`

   Note: This will also work for more than two possible options; simply separate additional desired options with a comma.

Now your cell will have a dropdown with `Yes` and `No`. The user can also type these values without clicking the dropdown button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that you have a typo for the Source text value. It should be Yes;no - semicolon. With a comma at least with Excel 2016 I get Yes,No as a value.

Comment: @Daniel Dimitrov - The comma works fine with Excel 2010, which is what I'm running, so it is not a typo.  I cannot speak for Excel 2016 since that software didn't exist at the time this answer was written many years ago :). And semicolon does *not* work in Excel 2010, only comma works.

Comment: @PeterLang the link is dead

Comment: @Simon: Thanks, I removed my comment with the wrong link and added a working link to my answer.