# Enable data entry in Excel cell only if a dependent cell is filled and then limit the entries to either 1 or 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know how to these two steps separately, but don't know how to combine them.

Ensuring a cell can be filled only if a dependent cell is filled can be achieved via inserting a `=NOT(ISBLANK($A$1))` formula in the Data Validation prompt, as explained [here](https://trumpexcel.com/enable-data-entry-in-a-cell-in-excel-only-if-a-dependent-cell-is-filled/).

Limiting a cell to two possible values can be done via 'Data Validation' as explained in the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/333559/limit-an-excel-cell-to-one-of-two-possible-values) question.

But how can I combine these two features? I don't think one can have two data validation options on one same cell.

Comment: something like: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1)),OR(B1=0,B1=1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t need a drop-down list box, you can try a custom formula like: =AND((E1<>""),OR(F1=1,F1=0)).

[image]

If the action does not meet the conditions, you will get the following promp.

[image]